# I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 How can i install and play league of legends?

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux, snap-store

I moved from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 22.04, i'm kinda new to linux. I find it difficult to find solutions to many things. like installing LoL and Overwolf's Runepage auto-import Facecheck. So many apps i want to use but i can't find in Snap Store and anywhere else. Is this gonna happen with all videogames or only LoL ? and how can i install LoL and install Facecheck and play ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo snap install leagueoflegends --edge
```

Comment: thanks .. now what about Facecheck ? any idea ?

Comment: this page says "coming soon": https://download.curseforge.com/. so there is no Facecheck mod for linux right now. What about running a windows virtual machine for just running this game with Facecheck mod? explore the usage of qemu kvm. you can install and run windows in ubuntu

Comment: if i affect much RAM and resources to the VM i don't think i can play in full performance and it will be bad ingame lag and graphic crashes and fps drops and maybe even high ping .. no ? i thought of this already ..